# responsive center text in divi theme header

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive

Im using Divi 2.0 theme for one of my websites. I have a problem when trying to center thetext in a box and align the text in center on mobile version. I will attach pictures of my header desktop and mobile version. Where can be the problem, in the Divi css code?

[image: Desktop version]

[image: mobile version]

The url of my webiste is http://mupcku.com

Comment: The problem is not the `center`, it's the missing space for the `font-size`. Just adjust the `font-size` for mobile browsers. One possible way could be using `media queries`.

Comment: Thanks! That really helps me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to keep the font-size and width and prevent long words from overflowing a box, the property you're looking for is `word-wrap: break-word`.

Comment: Yess this is usefull also! I will use this also i will arrange my font-size correctly and everything will be okay! Thank you a lot!

Comment: No worries! Glad I could be of service.

(P.S. It's considered good etiquette to mark the most helpful answer as accepted if it helped solve your problem.  This'll increase your reputation on the site)

Answer (score 0):

When the device width reaches around 480px, the following CSS line is causing your problem:

```
.et_pb_fullwidth_header .et_pb_fullwidth_header_container.center .header-content {
    width: 80%;
    ...
```

you could add the breakpoint at that weight and do something like:

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {
    .et_pb_fullwidth_header .et_pb_fullwidth_header_container.center .header-content {
        width: auto;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is very simple. This is because you have set margin of your row or section to 0px. No worries: just set it to default you will get your solution.
Or else check our Tutorial at [Tech Gigs](https://tech-gigs.co.in/custom-global-header-in-divi/)

In case still you are facing problem just hit a comment to us on our website.

Comment: Please refer to my comment on [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69606934/10871073) you have recently posted.