# Add CSS class to all heading HTML elements?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, class, tags

I'm currently working on a website for some school assignments.
I am using Wordpress with the Divi theme.

Online I found some CSS code, which lets me add a colored line under my text. I've been using this on all my headings.

- Here's an example of my headings: https://colindedeugd.nl/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/Header-Colored-Line-Example.jpg

The CSS code for it looks like this;

```
    .pa-color-highlight {
    text-decoration: none;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -.4em 0 rgba(48, 227, 255, 1);
    color: inherit;
}
```

To add this to my heading, I used some HTML code;

```
<h2><span class="pa-color-highlight">Background</span></h2>
```

My problem is that I have to manually add this HTML code everytime I want to use a heading. Simply converting my text to 'H2' in standard text editor ignores this CSS class.
**I was wondering if there was a way to automatically add this CSS class to all (H2) headings, sitewide.** Is there a simple solution for it? If so that would be a great help!

I've already tried adding the highlight CSS to the heading directly using CSS, but that looks like this:

```
h2 {
    text-decoration: none;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -.4em 0 rgba(48, 227, 255, 1);
    color: inherit;
    font-size: 45px;
}
```

- Example image;
  https://colindedeugd.nl/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/Header-Colored-Line-Example-2.jpg

The line fills the whole text field, instead of just underlining the text itself. If there's a simpler solution for this issue than the other thing, I would be more than happy!

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the *display: table* should meet your needs:

```
h2 {
    text-decoration: none;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -.4em 0 rgba(48, 227, 255, 1);
    color: inherit;
    display: table;
}
```

[image: H2 with display: table]

Comment: Yes!!!! This is what I was looking for! Thank you!
One note is that I had to change `color: inherit` to `color: black` to change the text color.
But this was exactly what I needed. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You're applying CSS properties to all of `h2` and h2 is a wide box containing the text which is `span` element.
So just change the last part of code from h2 to span

```
span {
    text-decoration: none;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -.4em 0 rgba(48, 227, 255, 1);
    color: inherit;
    font-size: 45px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! But we're not quite there yet. 

I've added this to my CSS, but my normal H2's `<h2>Heading 2</h2>`  are still not underlined, which means I'd still need to manually add the HTML.
Also, I would like to add a different colored line to H3, is there a way to seperate the span?

Sorry if I sound like a noob, I'm still pretty new to editing CSS and HTML myself and only know the absolute basics...

Answer (score 0):

[image]
I'm assuming you didn't understand my previous comment so this is an explanation.
The tag `header` is not just the text its a full box of `width:auto` as you can see in the image above (second background).
In the code you sent you're giving the underline effect "box-shadow" to the header `h2` which will as explained gives it to the whole box. The text you have written inside `h2` are inside a `span` tag which will only cover the text not the whole box, so giving the effect to only the `span` tag will fix your problem, and about other `h2` tags not getting underline, is because you switched the effect to `span`, so you have to also put the other `h2` inside a `span`.
And since you want to add `h3` with different properties, the optimal way to do it is add `span` to all headers + add class name or id for `h2` different than `h3` and use that class name or id to set the CSS. for example:

```
HTML:
<h2><span id="TextInsideH2" class="pa-color-highlight">Background</span></h2>
<h3><span id="TextInsideH3" class="pa-color-highlight">Background</span></h3>

CSS:
#TextInsideH2{css properties here}
#TextInsideH3{different css properties here}
```

Comment: This definitely helps, thanks for taking the time to write this up!

Answer (score 0):

As previously said, skip the span part and apply it directly to the h2. Header elements are block level by default which is why you see the background/fat underline stretch across the whole parent element. You'll have to add `display:inline-block;`, `display:inline-flex;` or `display:table;` for example to have the underline only covering the width of the h2 text though:

```
h2 {
  display:inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -.4em 0 rgba(48, 227, 255, 1);
  color: inherit;
}
```

Not knowing how the rest of how your markup looks, this should work as a solution for you.
If you want to dig deeper, you can get this effect with pseudo elements. That will give you even better control over how you want that line/background to look. Here's an example:

```css
h2 {
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
}

h2::before {
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  bottom:-2px;
  left:-5px;
  right:-5px;
  height:14px;
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(48, 227, 255), rgba(32, 160, 255));
  z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<h2>Background</h2>
<p>A paragraph</p>
```

Here's some more info what pseudo classes can do: [CSS-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/pseudo-element-roundup/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Wordpress with DIVI Theme installed you don't have to add Any css code as Divi has all functionality to manage such design aspects.

Just open setting of your text module and Navigate to "Design Tab"

For more information check our tutorial at [Tech Gigs](https://tech-gigs.co.in/custom-global-header-in-divi/)

Comment: Excessive promotion of a specific product/resource may be perceived by the community as **spam**. Take a look at the [help], specially [What kind of behavior is expected of users?](//stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)'s last section: _Avoid overt self-promotion_. You might also be interested in [How to not be a spammer](//stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) and [How do I advertise on Stack Overflow?](//www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/advertising).